# bypass messenger must install a new version (forced upgrade)

Tags: instant-messaging, windows-live-messenger

Is there anyway to keep my old (version 8.5) messenger ?
For some reason it doesn't let me log in and want to force an upgrade (I really don't like the new versions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.phuketbutler.com/node/1072

1. Right Click on your "Windows Live Messenger's icon
2. Click on Properties you will see many tabs,Shortcut,Compatibility,General,Security,Details
   and Previous Version.
3. Click on Compatibility Tab in This Tab you will see "Compatibility
   Mode"
4. Check in front of Run this Program in compatibility mode for:

   - if you use Windows XP, Select Windows NT or 2000 (Msnplus can't
     run    on this mode)    [if you use
     Windows Vista or 7, Select Windows
     Server 2003(SP1)(    msnplus can run
     on this mode]
5. Apply and OK this setting
6. Let's enjoy on your Windows Live Messenger 8.0 and 8.5

I haven't tried it personally . But sounds like its working.

Comment: It works.... (and here are some more chars)

Comment: Fantastic, in an attempt to downgrade from the 2011 Messenger which is a complete disaster and abomination, I was then given a sily popup forcing me to upgrade back to 2011 or else I couldn't sign in... thanks to your answer I'm happily logged into the old messenger! woot!